# How to encourage devirtualisation of an unused abstract base class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, compiler-optimization, devirtualization

I have a shallow class hierarchy (minimal reproducible code example at the bottom) where I'm using an abstract base class to hold mostly common logic between a bunch of related classes, with a virtual function (`modifier()`) that child classes override to influence behaviour of a shared method in the parent (`logic()`).

There is no real polymorphism involved in the code i.e. I am not passing the child classes as a parent class pointer anywhere, in fact the base class is not mentioned anywhere other than the declaration of the child classes and to enforce this, the base class is even in an anonymous namespace (static linkage). The child classes are declared final, created as themselves and kept that way, to outside code the hierarchy might as well not exist. I am basically using the inheritance mechanism to just mechanically share most of the code between various related classes, without having to do a lot of copypasting myself.

Given that, I would think these classes would be prime candidates for devirtualisation, but it seems to not kick in in current compilers like gcc 13.2 or clang 17.0. The compiler can elide vtables in very very trivial cases, but just a little bit of indirection and vtables are generated and used even at `-O3`; see this godbolt:

https://godbolt.org/z/67479h619

Is there any way to make this code more optimisation-friendly and get rid of the vtables more reliably? Does the standard say anything about this optimisation or does it all depend on the compilers and the direction of the wind? Or is the only good way to solve this is "manual devirtualisation" i.e. getting rid of the virtual function entirely by simply copy pasting `logic()` into every child class by hand?

Here is the same sample code from the above godbolt:

```cpp
// devirtualisation test

namespace ns {

namespace {

struct Base {
    int common() { return 3; }
    virtual int modifier() = 0;
    int logic(int n) {
        return (n * modifier()) % common();
    }
};

} // namespace <anonymous>

struct ChildA final : Base {
    int modifier() { return 2; }
};

struct ChildB final : Base {
    int modifier() { return 3; }
};

struct ChildC final : Base {
    int modifier() { return 4; }
};

} //namespace ns

using namespace ns;

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// get* functions to confuse compilers a little

ChildA getA() {
    return ChildA();
}

ChildB getB() {
    return ChildB();
}

int main() {
    cout << getA().logic(2) << "\n";
    cout << getB().logic(2) << "\n";
    cout << ChildC().logic(2) << "\n";
}
```

Obviously the real example is a bit more sophisticated; it's a bunch of classes for iteratively going through nodes of a tree, where the virtual function is responsible for deciding when the walk stops and returns a value. So I can create an iterator for an inorder, preorder, leaf-only, etc. walks just by overriding that method. Here's a godbolt if that seems like a useful test (the counterparts for `logic()` and `modifier()` are `bstiterbase<T>::walk()` and `bstiterbase<T>::stop()` respectively):

https://godbolt.org/z/7MjzfbzWb

Comment: The desired optimizations here pretty much require link-time optimization. It is unclear whether the appropriate LTO options were enabled for gcc.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You seem to be correct, according to this godbolt adding your suggestion of `-flto`: https://godbolt.org/z/aMoGqahWP

But why is this the case? Can the compiler not prove the base class never "escapes" the translation unit, even from an anonymous namespace?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik actually NVM, even with `-flto -O3`, int the linked godbolt the vtables are still generated for the linked code, just mashed into the assembly, unless I'm misreading it? The assembly comments and the LLVM IR both mention vtables. In the trivial example LTO optimises them away fine, which just makes me think I have to come up with a more convoluted example to test on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `Base` being defined in an anonymous namespace means that trying to define any of your derived classes in another translation unit would be an ODR violation (because `Base` would refer to a different class in a different, new, anonymous namespace).

Secondly, calling a function on a prvalue will always be devirtualised. So will calling a function on a glvalue which is typed as a `final` class. The first example you've given is completely devirtualised (i.e., there is no indirection into any vtable). The vtable can't be removed because it can be used in other translation units.

Third, in your bigger "real example", to devirtualise the call to `stop`, the compiler must entirely inline `step()` and `walk()`. So the tradeoff is the extra code size needed to do this vs the speed lost by just calling the virtual function.

If you want to force the compiler to do this, you can use the CRTP:

```cpp
// *Not* in an anonymous namespace
namespace detail {
template<typename Self>
struct Base {
    Self& self() { return static_cast<Self&>(*this); }
    int common() { return 3; }
    int logic(int n) {
        return (n * self().modifier()) % common();
    }
};
}

struct ChildA final : detail::Base<ChildA> {
    int modifier() { return 2; }
};

struct ChildB final : detail::Base<ChildB> {
    int modifier() { return 3; }
};

struct ChildC final : detail::Base<ChildC> {
    int modifier() { return 4; }
};

// Or if you have C++23
namespace detail {
struct Base {
    int common() { return 3; }
    int logic(this auto&& self, int n) {
        return (n * self.modifier()) % self.common();
    }
};
}

struct ChildA final : detail::Base {
    int modifier() { return 2; }
};

struct ChildB final : detail::Base {
    int modifier() { return 3; }
};

struct ChildC final : detail::Base {
    int modifier() { return 4; }
};
```

Comment: So the answer to this is CRTP, I see, thanks!

regarding ODR: yes, I knew that, the intent was very much for the base to be a private impl detail, and only the derived classes to be publically accessible. There's not really much logic behind it, this is very much a implement-knockoff-stdlib-over-weekend thing. I thought that fact would help in the optimisation anyway.

And on that matter, yeah, I should've noticed that the vtables is only being copied in the assembly and never used. But I still find it weird because I didn't expect the outside world to know about the base class at all.

Comment: I managed to get CRTP working with `bstiter`: https://godbolt.org/z/xnrqnTzhn

It was a bit involved, had to add [deducing this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/) to all calls involved in this pseudo-virtualisation, and add base as a friend class to the derived, because it seems `protected` doesn't go both ways.

Thanks again!